# Best way to have a page with different width

Tags: html, css, position, width, absolute

I have to create a page with this structure:

[image]

Where the RED part has width = 100% and BLUE (and GREEN) part has width 885px.

I thought to create different width, some with width = 885px and the others with width 980px... but I think this is not the right approach... in fact if I have to change the width for example from 885px to 980 px

Another solution I think could be to have to div... the first one has width 100%; the second one, inside the first one, has width 885px. But I think could be difficult to place the green div at the same height/top of the red one on the back.

Which approach would you used to reach the goal?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to manage simple html like below:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap"></div>
</div>

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
}
.wrap{
  width: 885px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

When you only need full width div don't include `.wrap` in your html. And when you only need 885px width div exclude `.wrapper` in your html.

Comment: But all div inside the "wrap" inherit the width=885px... and that'ok... 
Now.. all div should have width = 100%, must be inside the div "wrapper"... correct? if so, the should have position absolute to go back (or in front) of the blue part.. correct?

Comment: I can clearly see in your picture that my layout works perfectly without using absolute positioning, or if you have any doubt and confusion use absolute as you can manage...

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick example of how you could do this [right here](http://jsfiddle.net/michaelvandeweerd/nh358knm/1/). I just made two classes, one that has a width of `100%` (red `div`), and one that has a fixed width (blue `div`, I used `450px` in my example). The green `div` is just a blue `div` inside a red `div`. I hope my example answers all the questions you have. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can manage the red with green band and sencond red band positioning absolutely in a main container, that also contains the blue one with a width. To explain it better i've created a JsFiddle please follow the link to see it working:

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/q91a7jr6/)

I've use the approach suggested @C-link Nepal, but I think to put red bars this isn't enough.

HTML:

```
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="redgreen">
        <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
<div class="foot">  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.top {
    background-color: red;
    height: 50px;
}

.main {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.green, .blue {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}

.redgreen {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
}

.red {
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Please note that most of CSS classes have height and background color to the pattern be drawn...